# How create phase delay between two square pulse

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio

I want create phase delay (as below figure) between each pulse generated from pigpio library, I using usleep to delay before generate pulse as in code, but all pusle generted is not phase difference (as the second figure). Please show me the way to done as the first figure.thanks

```
import sys, struct
from socket import*
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time, pigpio
delay_array1=[10,20,18,15]
##create 40khz pulse      
usleep = lambda x: time.sleep(x/1000000.0)
FREQ=40000
PWM1=2
PWM2=3
PWM3=4
PWM4=21
GPIO=[PWM1,PWM2,PWM3,PWM4]
_channels = len(GPIO)#_channels=26
print(_channels)

_dc=[0]*_channels #_dc=[0,..,0]; 26 phan tu 0
print (_dc)

_micros=1000000/FREQ

old_wid = None

def set_dc(channel, dc):

  global old_wid

  if dc < 0:
     dc = 0
  elif dc > _micros:
     dc = _micros

  _dc[channel] = dc

  for c in range(_channels):#c run 0..25
     d = _dc[c]
     g = GPIO[c]
     if d == 0:
        pi.wave_add_generic([pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<g, _micros)])
     elif d == _micros:
        pi.wave_add_generic([pigpio.pulse(1<<g, 0, _micros)])
     else:

        pi.wave_add_generic(
           [pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<g, d), pigpio.pulse(1<<g, 0, _micros-d)])

  new_wid = pi.wave_create()
  print('id:',new_wid)
  if old_wid is not None:
     pi.wave_send_using_mode(new_wid, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC)

     #Spin until the new wave has started.
     while pi.wave_tx_at() != new_wid: # returns the id of the waveform currently being transmitted
         pass
     #It is then safe to delete the old wave
     pi.wave_delete(old_wid)

  else:
#transmits the waveform with id wave_id, repeats until wave_tx_stop is called
#or another call to wave_send_* is made
     pi.wave_send_repeat(new_wid)
  old_wid = new_wid

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
  exit(0)
## calls a user supplied function (a callback) whenever the specified GPIO edge is detected
#def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
#    print (gpio, level, tick)
#cb1 = pi.callback(13, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
#data1= cb1.tally()
#print (data2)
# set wave GPIO to output mode
for g in GPIO:
  pi.set_mode(g, pigpio.OUTPUT)
usleep(delay_array1[0])
set_dc(0,_micros/2)
usleep(delay_array1[1])
set_dc(1,_micros/2)
usleep(delay_array1[2])       
set_dc(2,_micros/2)
usleep(delay_array1[3])
set_dc(3,_micros/2)

time.sleep(60)
pulses=pi.wave_get_pulses()
print(pulses)
pi.wave_tx_stop()

if old_wid is not None:
  pi.wave_delete(old_wid)
pi.wave_clear()
cb1.reset_tally()
cb1.cancel()
pi.stop()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet from a Python class to generate PWM with waves.

- self.used[g] is True if GPIO g is providing PWM.
- self.pS[g] is where the pulse starts within the cycle as a percentage (0=start, 50=middle, 100=end).
- self.pL[g] is the length of the pulse as a percentage of the cycle (0=off, 50=half cycle length, 1=fully on).
- self.micros is the length of each wave (25µs for 40kHz).

I will be publishing the code as a complete class within a day or so.  It will probably replace the current wave_PWM example at [pigpio examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Index).

```py
def update(self):

   null_wave = True

   for g in range(self.GPIO):

      if self.used[g]:

         null_wave = False

         on = int(round(self.pS[g] / 100.0 * self.micros))
         length = int(round(self.pL[g] / 100.0 * self.micros))

         if length == 0:
            self.pi.wave_add_generic([pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<g, self.micros)])
         elif length == self.micros:
            self.pi.wave_add_generic([pigpio.pulse(1<<g, 0, self.micros)])
         else:
            _off = (on + length) % self.micros
            if on < _off:
               self.pi.wave_add_generic([
                  pigpio.pulse(   0,    0,                on),
                  pigpio.pulse(1<<g,    0,         _off - on),
                  pigpio.pulse(   0, 1<<g, self.micros - _off),
                  ])
            else:
               self.pi.wave_add_generic([
                  pigpio.pulse(   0,    0,              _off),
                  pigpio.pulse(   0, 1<<g,        on - _off),
                  pigpio.pulse(1<<g,    0, self.micros - on),
                  ])

   if not null_wave:

      if not self.stop:

         new_wid = self.pi.wave_create()

         if self.old_wid is not None:

            self.pi.wave_send_using_mode(
               new_wid, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC)

            # Spin until the new wave has started.

            while self.pi.wave_tx_at() != new_wid:
               pass

            # It is then safe to delete the old wave.
            self.pi.wave_delete(self.old_wid)

            print(self.old_wid)

         else:

            self.pi.wave_send_repeat(new_wid)

         self.old_wid = new_wid
```

Comment: thanks @joan very much. I want question is that update(self) function which similar as set_dc(GPIO,dc) function , it only difference is added pigpio.pulse(0,0,on) that can create delay time before pulse generated, are you right? But when we use "self.pi.wave_send_repeat(new_wid)"  is that whether pigpio.pulse(0,0,on) have repeatly too? it only created a  only time, after that is generate pulse 40khz continuously?

Comment: @Gab I still am not clear as to what you want to do.  I have put the new example code at http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_wavePWM_py

Comment: I only want to pulse generated that only delay initial then still is pulse 40khz as figure in link: http://imgur.com/a/zFTin

Comment: it like as create offset for a pulse

Comment: That's what the new class does.  Each GPIO may have a different offset from the start of the cycle.

Comment: in your new class, it can create a start time have resolution to 1us? (Example I want  start time for pulse on GPIO 1 is 2 and for GPIO 2 is 3 =>> phased delay between them is 1 us but it only dislay 5us) . I tried but picscope only display the min resolution is 5us with any phase delay between two pulses is a number not divisible by 5 as in figure: http://imgur.com/a/q26fi